# Boost ASIO: Connection Refused

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am receiving the following error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_implboost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error >'
what():  connect: Connection refused
Aborted (core dumped)

I am trying to connect on two different machines on the same network; this works if I use local host. Any suggestions on how to resolve ?

Client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
using ip::tcp;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
     boost::asio::io_service io_service;

     tcp::socket socket(io_service);

 socket.connect( tcp::endpoint( boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.158.112.3"), 1234 ));

 const string msg = "Hello from Client!\n";
 boost::system::error_code error;
 boost::asio::write( socket, boost::asio::buffer(msg), error );
 if( !error ) {
    cout << "Client sent hello message!" << endl;
 }
 else {
    cout << "send failed: " << error.message() << endl;
 }
 
       boost::asio::streambuf receive_buffer;
       boost::asio::read(socket, receive_buffer, boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);
      if( error && error != boost::asio::error::eof ) {
       cout << "receive failed: " << error.message() << endl;
    }
    else {
    const char* data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(receive_buffer.data());
    cout << data << endl;
   }
return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
using ip::tcp;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

   string read_(tcp::socket & socket) {
    boost::asio::streambuf buf;
    boost::asio::read_until( socket, buf, "\n" );
    string data = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(buf.data());
    return data;
 }  
   void send_(tcp::socket & socket, const string& message) {
        const string msg = message + "\n";
        boost::asio::write( socket, boost::asio::buffer(message) );
 }

 int main() {
      boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 1234 ));
  tcp::socket socket_(io_service);
  acceptor_.accept(socket_);
  string message = read_(socket_);
  cout << message << endl;
  send_(socket_, "Hello From Server!");
  cout << "Servent sent Hello message to Client!" << endl;
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Connection refused, firewall maybe? Try disabling it.

Comment: Your server will only accept a single connection then exit, are you sure it's still running when you run the client?

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned, your serer only accepts 1 connection, then exits.

Other than that the only reasonable explanations are:

- the hard-coded IP address is wrong
- the acceptor is not binding to the interface with that address (firewalls may be involved).

Here's a simplified take on client and server, which accepts multiple connections and shows that things are working with a live demo (my ip address is different, obviously):

- File `server.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace asio = boost::asio;
   using asio::ip::tcp;
   using namespace std::string_view_literals;

   std::string read_string(tcp::socket & socket) {
       std::string s;
       auto n = read_until(socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(s), "\n");
       return s.substr(0, n); // CAUTION: discarding any remaining buffer!
   }

   void send_(tcp::socket& socket, const std::string& message) {
       write(socket, std::array{asio::buffer(message), asio::buffer("\n"sv)});
   }

   int main() {
       asio::io_service io_service;
       tcp::acceptor    acceptor(io_service, {{}, 1234});

       while (true) {
           tcp::socket c = acceptor.accept();
           std::cout << std::quoted(read_string(c)) << std::endl;
           send_(c, "Hello From Server!");
           c.close();
       }
   }
  ```
- File `client.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <iostream>

   namespace asio = boost::asio;
   using asio::ip::tcp;

   int main() {
       asio::io_service io_service;

       tcp::socket socket(io_service);

       socket.connect(tcp::endpoint(
           boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.50.225"), 1234));

       const std::string msg = "Hello from Client!\n";

       boost::system::error_code error;
       write(socket, asio::buffer(msg), error);
       std::cout << "send: " << error.message() << std::endl;

       asio::streambuf receive_buffer;
       read(socket, receive_buffer /*, asio::transfer_all()*/, error);

       std::cout << "receive (" << error.message() << "): " << &receive_buffer
                 << std::endl;
   }
  ```

Note the simplifications around buffering and error handling. Also note the CAUTION comment.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Demo also live on Coliru http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b24e2439e0b88bd2

Comment: Thank you, @sehe but when I try your example, I receive the following:
       server.cpp:7:23: error: ‘string_view_literals’ is not a namespace-name
      using namespace std::string_view_literals;
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
server.cpp:7:43: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
  using namespace std::string_view_literals;
                                           ^
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yeah, don't use string view literals if your compiler [doesn't support them yet](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv). Perhaps you should tell us the language version you are using (or switch to a higher language version). Here's a completely c++11 version online: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6ed1f2a953d6326